# Identical CSS rules look different in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm rewriting a page in Angular.
I copied all the styles and layout. But colors are not applied properly.
After inspecting original and new pages I don't see why they are different. I think it is either CSS specificity or Angular style encapsulation. Can you please help?

Here are my styles, I copied them one to one:

```
.table-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: -1px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    .main-head {
        display: flex;

        .head-inner {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .table-col {
            background-color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }

    .table-col {
        height: 45px;
        padding: 0 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;

        &.locked {
            background-color: darkkhaki;
        }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I tried to reproduce with the scss you provided but got the expected result of `.locked` overriding the other. Do you have a reproducible example by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 things that can affect styles in angular
1 - component tags are present in the resulting html, thus selectors containing `>` like `.parent > .child`  could break.
2 - style incapsulation - most likely this one is the reason of your troubles. - all of the css selectors become more complex (some attributes are added to every selector) and because of this, css doesn't affect any elements that aren't part of the components template.

The thing one your screens happends because of these huge selectors are of increased specificity and color #fff became stronger because of that.

I would suggest 2 options

1 - remove styles encapsulation

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

or 2 - make styles selectors simpler and more linear

```
.table-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: -1px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
 .table-col {
     height: 45px;
     padding: 0 5px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;

     &.locked {
       background-color: darkkhaki;
     }
}
```

with this approach selectors won't grow in size that much. some changes would still be required because of how your css is structured, but far less than with your current situation

Comment: I would suggest not doing #1 99% of the time, view encapsulation is your friend if used correctly.

Comment: this is the case where the app is transfered from another ecosystem. it can be really a lot of work to transform all the styles. with no incapsulation it would just work as an old app and it would be the good use case for omitting encapsulation

Comment: If that were the case I'd omit them as an external style declared in the angular.json styles in the build config as a separate file. That way view encapsulation wouldn't apply but you would retain it for future work in your components etc and avoid bad practices.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not allowed to use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` or `::ngDeep`. I just reorganized my css. When I asked the question I wanted to know why this has happened more than how to fix it. Thank you!